# How to SELECT records from a temp table applying a specific condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have dumped a file into a temp table and trying to pull records where the score is <= 100. The column has values for example, 3, 4.50, 10.02, 99.88,99,99, 100, 100.2, 100, 116, 116.44 etc. I need only 3, 4.50, 10.02,99.88,99,99,100. When I tried the below, it does not give the proper result. Could anyone advise?

```sql
SELECT CAST(sum AS numeric ),* FROM temp WHERE sum >= '100' ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here. First, you're using the `>=` operator instead of the `<=` operator. Second, `sum` seems to be a string column, so the comparison is performed lexicographically. You could apply the same casting you've applied in the select list and compare the value to a number literal `100`, not a string literal `'100'`:

```sql
SELECT CAST(sum AS numeric ),* FROM temp WHERE CAST(sum AS numeric) >= 100;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. It worked perfectly.

Comment: Let's expand somewhat on answer from @Mureinki. It is not just a syntactical difference. It has very real consequences on the result. Keep in mind that a text the value '20' is greater then the value '100', or any other value starting with '1'. Second as constructed you will get the SUM column twice, as caste and result of selecting * (all columns). (see [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0c75026a9032f7c77216ae763e3dd67a)). Finally, SUM is very poor as a column name as it is a SQL reserved word and a Postgres aggregate function name. At best it leads to confusion.